# Unwanted spacing in datetree template

Tags: org-mode, org-capture, template

I have an issue with unwanted spacing when I'm adding entries to datetree. This is the template I'm using, stripped to simplest for the purpose of testing:

```
("p" "Progress" entry (file+olp+datetree "~/org/progress.org") "* %?" :tree-type week))
```

What I'm getting as a result is this:

```
* 2022

** 2022-W52

*** 2022-12-28 Wednesday
**** something
```

and what I would like to get is this:

```
* 2022
** 2022-W52
*** 2022-12-28 Wednesday
**** something
```

I have to stress that this spacing or empty lines are still there even if I replace entry for plain or tree-type for any other option. Also, `:empty-lines`, `empty-lines-before` or `empty-lines-after` are not making any change as far as I can tell along with few other variables I tried setting following some advice I gathered reading similar questions.

I'm not sure why this is happening to begin with, why would anyone want so much spacing and wasted lines in org file and I would bet that I had datetrees without it earlier but I have no idea what changed.
Any help much appreciated, I tried every idea that came to my mind.

Comment: What is the value of the variable `org-blank-before-new-entry`? You can check with `C-h v org-blank-before-new-entry`. Please update your question with that value.

Comment: Both `heading` and `plain-list-item` are `auto`, but I did change them to nil and nothing was different.

Comment: Try starting with an empty file and the `auto` setting: that seems to work for me (although there might be interactions with other settings). I think `auto` uses the surrounding context to figure out whether to add newlines, so you might get misleading results if your existing files already has empty lines where you don't want them. I would also start with `emacs -Q -l /path/to/minimal/init.el` with only the setting of `org-blank-before-new-entry` to make sure there are no interactions with other settings. I haven't tried with the `nil` setting yet.

Comment: I just tried default `auto` setting but with no luck. I even deleted the file and it got recreated automatically but I'm getting the same result. Even if I create older entries, manually remove empty lines and then add entry with capure, it still makes them. Something is really strange here and I have no idea what to do.